# What is a good way to increase the rate of generation of my discipline?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

Playing as a demonhunter, my discipline just regenerates too slowly and it often runs out when I try to kite difficult to kill champions/bosses with [Vault](http://d3db.com/skill/i/vault) along with [Tumble](http://d3db.com/runestone/i/vault/d). I am aware of quite a few ways to increase Hatred regeneration, but not for discipline.

What are some of the ways to increase its regeneration and/or increase its maximum amount?

Comment: I know there's a stat that increased max discipline.

Comment: There is both +discipline and +regen gear I believe. Get lucky with drops/crafting is likely the answer. There's also some passives that help. I'll write up a proper answer later when I can get in game if there's still nothing here.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know there was gear that increased discipline (have encountered none so far).

Comment: Anyway you're supposed to run out of Discipline if you don't manage it carefully. If you're struggling you can consider to switch one of your others skill to [Preparation](http://d3db.com/skill/i/preparation), possibly runed with [Invigoration](http://d3db.com/runestone/i/preparation/b) or [Focused Mind](http://d3db.com/runestone/i/preparation/c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various affixes that can appear on gear such as Confident and Diligent that increase maximum discipline. I've only been able to find Hatred regen in D3db, so it looks like I may have been mistaken about that part in my comment. You can stack a little +discipline gear to give you a bit more of a buffer, but that will only help so much in prolonged fights. These affixes seem to be available from the very start of the game, at least according to D3db. I can't remember exactly when I started noticing them on my own play through, but that's down to luck anyway.

There are also a few passive abilities that can help, depending on what skills you use in your build:

- [Vengeance](http://d3db.com/skill/i/vengeance): Gain 2 discipline whenever you pick up a health globe.
- [Night Stalker](http://d3db.com/skill/i/night-stalker): Critical strikes have a chance to gain 1 discipline. (Possibly pair with [Sharpshooter](http://d3db.com/skill/i/sharpshooter) and [Bait the Trap](http://d3db.com/runestone/i/caltrops/e) for more crits)
- [Custom Engineering](http://d3db.com/skill/i/custom-engineering): Increases duration of some of your discipline using abilities.
- [Perfectionist](http://d3db.com/skill/i/perfectionist): Decreases the cost of all abilities that use discipline by 10%

Other things that may help:

- All of your `Defensive` skills have runes which reduce their cost.

Answer (score 2):

Natalya's Set has a four item bonus to increase Discipline Regen by 2 per second

Comment: yes, and this is the main reason why natalya's mark (the ring in the set) is so expensive